# Unity warning CS0618: 'Application.LoadLevel(string)' is obsolete: 'Use SceneManager.LoadScene'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, warnings

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string LevelToLoad;
    private float timer = 10f;
    private Text timerSeconds;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f2");
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(LevelToLoad);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code I have but it won't be suitable for my unity 3.1.2

Can someone please tell me what to adjust so the code would fit my unity v3.1.2

Comment: Did you read the warning and look at the documentation? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning says "Use SceneManager.LoadScene" you should use `SceneManager.LoadScene` instead of `Application.LoadLevel`. The only difference is that `SceneManager.LoadScene` uses indexes of the scenes ordered in Build Settings and `Application.LoadLevel` uses a string of the scene name.

Conclusion: Change `Application.LoadLevel` to `SceneManager.LoadScene` and pass in the index of the scene you want to load.

If you don't have `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement` make sure you include that because `SceneManager.LoadScene` uses that.